# How can I create Custom-Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to create a custom bottom navbar, but I don't want it to be a rectangular style. I just want one big circle (it's gonna be an image) that a user can click on as a button.

I know I can customize the way the bottom bar looks like, but I am not sure how to add the image in the center and make it overflow the original boundaries of the bar. For now I have something like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *item3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize
                          target:self
                          action:nil];

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, flexibleSpace, item2, flexibleSpace, item3, nil];

self.toolbarItems = items;`
```

Here is a picture for illustration. Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: try my answer, custom navigation bar is easily implemented through that way

Comment: Did the two answers help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an Custom Navigation Bar takes a lot of work so in instead you could make an custom button over the image and when the user clicks on it will change the image or the action (user "taps" on the image alert pops up :):

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *onlyImageVIew;
    BOOL firstImage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *onlyImageVIew;
-(IBAction)buttonClicked;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize firstImage, secondImage;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked {
    if (firstImage == YES) {
        onlyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
        firstImage == NO
    }
    else {
        onlyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourSecondImage.png"];
        firstImage == YES
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // when view loaded, load the first image only.
    firstImage = YES;
    onlyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourLaunchImage.png"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps that i usually accept to customize `UINavigationBar`

1.Hide the navigation bar throughout your project, at the appdelegate class.

2.Add `UIImageView` with the required image in the place of `UINavigationBar`.

3.Add `UIButton`s at required positions on the image view and you can add button images as you need.

4.On button click, push the `UIViewController` yourself.

This is the only way to create a custom navigation bar, the only inconvenience is, you need to push and pop the `UIViewControllers` yourselves.

Regards